# How do I upload file in nodejs to a server?

Tags: node.js, upload

I have bean searching the Internet on how to upload a file to a web server from nodejs. I found some stuff but it told you how to upload to a nodejs server and not some other web server. So my qutions is how can I upload a file using nodejs to a web serve?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [http](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http.request) module and pipe a file stream to the request.

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
});

req.on('error', function(err) {
  throw err;
});

fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(req);
```

Comment: Can you make it more detailed for example where do I put the URL to the site I want to upload to. I am a beginner in node.

Comment: That goes in the `options`. I linked to the `http.request` documentation that lists all the options you can use. You might also want to look at the [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request). It makes it so you only have to do `fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(request.put(url));`

Comment: ok so that is all great now how do I get the file on the server. What do I put in the php file on the server and thx for the help